# Passing options to js compiler on meteor

Tags: webpack, meteor, babeljs, vscode-jsconfig

We are adding a `jsconfig` file to the root of a meteor project to add short hands form imports.

For instance instead of `import UserMutations from '../../api/Users/mutations';` we would like to write `import UserMutations from '@api/Users/mutations';`

This is an example jsconfig file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@api/*": ["api/*"],
    }
  }
}
```

When we add this our short hand imports recognized as `npm` packages that are missing.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meteor's build system uses babel under the hood. So, you can solve your task with a plugin 'module-resolver':

Install npm package:

> meteor npm i babel-plugin-module-resolver

Create **.babelrc** at the root of your meteor project:

```json
{
  "plugins": [
    [
      "module-resolver",
      {
        "alias": {
          "@api": "./imports/api"
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Then import

```js
imports
api
   users
      index.js
      utils.js
...
```

```js
import { Users } from '@api/users';
import { SomeUtils } from '@api/users/utils.js';
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like what you are referring to is
https://guide.meteor.com/build-tool.html#typescript. Accordingly, your file
needs to be called `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure it works for js(jsconfig.json)